# Error when loading an .mat file using R

Tags: r, matlab

I try to load a .mat file using the R.matlab library. When I run:

```
 x <- readMat("MPL.mat")
```

I get this error however.

```
Error in mat5ReadTag(this) : 
 Unknown data type. Not in range [1,19]: 18569
In addition: Warning message: 
In readMat5Header(this, firstFourBytes = firstFourBytes) :
Unknown MAT version tag: 512. Will assume version 5.
```

Anybody who experienced this and has a way to deal with this?

Im familiar with this post: [R.matlab/readMat : Error in readTag(this)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11318331/r-matlab-readmat-error-in-readtagthis) but alternatives ways didnt work for me...

Comment: What mat version was used when saving?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is related to how is saved your **"MPL.mat"**. If you save by default in MATLAB, it probably won't work using **R.matlab** in **R**.

When I saved my .mat object in **'-v7'** or **'-v6'** i did not have problems, but the R.matlab documentation suggest to save in **'-v6'** (Pag.25 in [R.matlab package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/R.matlab/R.matlab.pdf)). For example, I saved 2 matrices (A and B) in **'MPL.mat'**.

```
save('MPL.mat','A', 'B', '-v7')
```

I could read in R:

```
require(R.matlab)
data <- readMat("MPL.mat")
View(data$A)
View(data$B)
```